# checking collision between rectangle and a sector of circle efficiently

Tags: python, math, vector, pygame, geometry

hey I wanted  to know if someone knew a code for checking collision between a rect and a sector of a circle, I know how to do it but the way I would do it is unefficient, here is the basic theory:

```
def is_inside_sector(rect, circle_center, radius, sector_point_A, sector_point_B):
#the rect is a tuple with the coordinate of the 4 corners
#the sector_point_A is the point on the edge of the sector and the circle
#the sector_point_B is the other one

    angle_A = sector_point_A.angle_to(vec(radius, 0)) % 360
    #calculate the angle of the first sector point

    angle_B = sector_point_B.angle_to(vec(radius, 0)) % 360
    #same for the second one

    for corner in rect:
        if circle_center.distance_to(corner) <= radius:
            if corner.angle_to(vec(radius, 0)) <= angle_A and corner.angle_to(vec(radius, 0)) >= angle_B:
                return True
        else:
            return False
        #this checks if any corner is in the sector, if yes, the rect and the sector collide
```

aight now I know the code has many flaws but I didnt complete it.

there are possibility that the rect and the sector collide without any corner of the rect being inside the sector, I would fix that by checking if any of the 3 corners of the sector (circle_center, sector_point_A, sector_point_B) would be inside the rect.

simple stuff and it would be a really good collision checking BUT! you gotta check 7 point! this is insanly slow, you gotta check if any of the corners of the rect is inside the sector and you gotta check if any of the corners of the sector is inside the rect, it will give you 100% accuracy but it is so slow.

is there any way I can check the collision of a sector and a rect without making an absurde function?

thanks alot if you help me on that, if you need I will make a real function testing the 7 points as I explained, the one I wrote was made on the go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you mean, by sector *S* of a circle, [the Wikipedia definition: ⌔](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_sector).
You need three functions:

1. Is a given point *p* in the sector *S*?
2. Do two segments intersect?
3. Does a segment intersect a circular arc?

I don't see how you can cover all cases without these three. All three have been
explored extensively, and code can be found all over the web.

---

[image: Sector]

---

Comment: thanks for the reply! your image helped me alot! I havent been able to find codes for that kind of collision, maybe I dont search with the right terms but if you have a link I would be gratefull! having three function that arent really small would be too much performance loss I think, maybe I will just make the hitbox a 90° triangle instead of a pie, no one will notice :P